# How to set cmake, in order to add txt files into working directory as resource?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("test.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

I got this output "Unable to open file". 
The files `test.txt`, `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp` are in the same directory. IDE is CLion.

How to set the `CMakeLists.txt`, in order to add the `test.txt` file into the working directory as resource?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `file(COPY` idiom:

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt
     DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

But may I also suggest [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) with the `COPYONLY` option. In this way, when `test.txt` is modified, CMake will reconfigure and regenerate the build. If you don't need that, just use `file(COPY`

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```

You will also see many people using `add_custom_command` to copy files, but that is more useful when you must copy a file in between build steps:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET untitled POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.txt)
```

I think in your case, the first example is most appropriate, but now you have tools in your toolbox for all scenarios.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way, which can copy multiple files into the binary directory one time?

Comment: Definitely. Using the `GLOB` keyword: `file(GLOB MY_FILES "*.txt") file(COPY ${MY_FILES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`