# Problem trying to open a file with ifstream using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

/* 
Defines the class Shader. 
*/

I am developing an application in C++ with OpenGL and CMake. The structure of my directories is:

- tanx

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - ext  (contains GLFW and glad)
  - src

    - TanX.cpp
    - TanX.h
    - math (contains a couple of math methods; not very relevant for my problem)
    - Shader

      - Shader.h
      - vertex.glsl
      - fragment.glsl
      - CMakeLists.txt

Shader.h ist mainly supposed to read vertex and fragment shader sources from files, compile them and link them to a Shader program. It looks like this:

```
#ifndef _SHADER_H
#define _SHADER_H

#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <glad.h>


class shader_exception :std::exception {
private:
    const char* text;
public:
    shader_exception(const char* text)
        : text(text) {}
    virtual const char* what() const {
        return text;
    }
};

class Shader {
private:
    std::string* vertex_source = new std::string();
    std::string* fragment_source = new std::string();
    unsigned int vao, vbo, vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
public:
    Shader(const char* vertex_source_path, const char* fragment_source_path) {
        std::ifstream file_reader;
        file_reader.open(vertex_source_path);
        std::string line;

        if (file_reader.is_open()) {
            while (getline(file_reader, line)) {
                vertex_source->append(line + "\n");
            }
            file_reader.close();
        }
        else 
            throw shader_exception("Could not open vertex shader source file");

        file_reader.open(fragment_source_path);  // this is where I get an unhandled exception dialog box
        if (file_reader.is_open()) {
            while (getline(file_reader, line)) {
                fragment_source->append(line + "\n");
            }
            file_reader.close();
        }
        else
            throw shader_exception("Could not open fragment shader file");
        const char** vertex_source_c = (const char**)malloc(vertex_source->size());
        *vertex_source_c = vertex_source->c_str();
        const char** fragment_source_c = (const char**)malloc(fragment_source->size());

        *fragment_source_c = fragment_source->c_str();
        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_source_c, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

        int success;
        glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        char infoLog[512];
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            throw shader_exception(infoLog);
        }

        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, fragment_source_c, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
        glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            throw shader_exception(infoLog);
        }

        program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
        glLinkProgram(program);
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            throw shader_exception(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);
    }

    Shader() = delete;

    void use() 
    {
        glUseProgram(program);
    }

    ~Shader() {
        glDeleteProgram(program);
    }
};

#endif
```

In TanX.cpp, I try to create a Shader object like this:

```
Shader shader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
```

As you can see, the shader source files I'd like to use are vertex.glsl and fragment.glsl which are located in the "Shader" - folder. In order to make them usable to ifstream, the CMakeLists.txt file in the Shader-folder looks like this (This is one of the options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995733/how-to-set-cmake-in-order-to-add-txt-files-into-working-directory-as-resource?rq=1#) to make files usable for the program):

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vertex.glsl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fragment.glsl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```

The top-level CMakeLists.txt file also contains

```
add_subdirectory("TanX/src/Shader")
```

so that the CMakeLists.txt file in Shader is executed.

The problem is that when I try to run my code in Visual Studio, I get an unhandled exception in the Shader.h file, at line 45 (where it tries to open fragment.glsl). It is a shader_exception, so apparently opening vertex.glsl failed. The details of the "Exception Unhandled" - Dialog Box: "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF43E4A388 in TanX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: shader_exception at memory location 0x00000028896FF608. occurred".  Now I have two questions

1) What do I neeed to do to get ifstream to open vertex.glsl (and then fragment.glsl after that)?
2) Why do I even get an unhandled exception error,  shouldn't construction of the Shader-object fail as soon as the exception gets thrown and that lead to the program not even reach line 45?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where I put the files to. I put them into the bin folder of the Shader folder, but as it is implemented in the header, the correct place is the bin folder of the top-level folder.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, but note that _where_ the code is written (in which source code file / header) has no bearing on the runtime interpretation of relative paths. Once compiled, the directory structure of your source code, if any, has been totally lost (ignoring debugging data). What matters is the process's _current working directory_ (CWD). This will depend on how and from where you launch the program.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, this ...

```
Shader* shader;
try {
    *shader = Shader("vertex.glsl", "fragment.glsl");
}
```

... is undefined behavior, because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (i.e., you haven't allocated any storage for the `Shader` object). This may not be the only problem but it is a critical one that must be fixed before you can debug further (because the behavior of the program afterward is unpredictable).

You probably meant to write:

```
shader = new Shader(...);
```

(And really you should use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for this rather than a bare pointer, but this is veering out of the scope of the original question. Among other benefits, it makes this kind of error easier to spot and avoid.)

---

As for other problems, have you checked that the program is run in the directory where the `.glsl` files are located? Relative paths passed to file streams are interpreted relative to the program's current working directory, not relative to the location of the original source file.

By my count, line 45 is ...

```
}
```

... so something seems to be misaligned. It would be helpful to post the actual program output and exception information (or dialog box contents) along with line numbers or an annotation showing the line the debugger is indicating.

Comment: Actually, I didn't really want to write
   shader = new Shader(...)

I tried to find a way to put the constructor in a try-catch-block, while still being able to use shader outside of it.

I did just scrap that idea for now though and updated the question.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to copy the (not very helpful) comments at the beginning of the file, leading to the line numbers being different. I added the comments now, so the line numbers should match now. I also added what the dialog box says.

Comment: As for the location of the files vs the program: That is why I have the CMakeLists file with the two configure_file(...) commands in that directory, I was hoping that would copy the files to where the program can access them (I got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995733/how-to-set-cmake-in-order-to-add-txt-files-into-working-directory-as-resource?rq=1#), probably should have mentioned that in the question as well).

Comment: OK, so the problem was actually the files being in the wrong folder. I put them into the bin folder of the Shader folder, but as everything is implemented in the header, the correct place to put them is the bin folder of the top-Level CMakeLists.txt file. Thanks for helping me figuring this out!

Comment: @Fusion Gotcha. `std::unique_ptr` is my go-to for that situation (when I need to create an object which will be accessible in the enclosing scope of e.g. a `try` block). Which boils down to what you tried, but is much safer. Glad you sorted it out. If the answer is helpful don't forget to vote and/or mark as the accepted answer.